# Having Trouble with Saving Object Detected Videos, the video is unplayable or it seems corrupt

Tags: python, opencv, yolov5

I am trying on Yolov5 running on OpenCV 4.8.

```
import sys
import cv2 
import imutils
from yoloDet import YoloTRT

# use path for library and engine file
model = YoloTRT(library="yolov5/build/libmyplugins.so", engine="yolov5/build/yolov5s.engine", conf=0.5, yolo_ver="v5")

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videos/testvideo1.mp4")

# Get the video's original properties
fps = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
width = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

# Define the codec for the output video
VIDEO_CODEC = 'MP4V'
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*VIDEO_CODEC)
output_video = cv2.VideoWriter("videos/output_video.mp4", 
    fourcc, 
    fps, 
    (width, height))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=600)
    detections, t = model.Inference(frame)
    
    # Write the current frame with detections to the output video
    output_video.write(frame)
    
    cv2.imshow("Output", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
output_video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Whenever I load the output I get 258 bytes file of the video that isn't working the test video is 7.5 MB. I've tried different formats of codec but its still showing the same problem.

I would apprecaite Any advice, thank you.